# Autostarting program with systemd service

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to set up Raspberry Pi with Raspbian to run a single program - PrintNode to manage printing. Program is placed in a file in desktop, and according to readme file, it is supposed to work by typing ./PrintNode inside the file - which works, when I do it.

I've found information, that the best way to handle autostart would be creating service through Unit file. So what I did was following:

Created new service file:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/PrintNode.service
```

content:

```
[Unit]
Description=PrintNode Service
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=idle
User=pi
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/PrintNode/PrintNode
Restart=always
RestartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Restarting

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable Printnode.service
```

Now, after rebooting and trying

```
sudo systemctl status PrintNode.service
```

it is active (running) however PrintNode application has not been started.

I suppose I did not understand fully the idea of using systemd autostart or there is an error somewhere.
I would really appreciate your help in understanding how it should work.

```
pi@print-server:~ $ cat /home/pi/Desktop/PrintNode
cat: /home/pi/Desktop/PrintNode: Is a directory

pi@print-server:~/Desktop/PrintNode $ ls
build.json      lib          readme.txt       sample_config.conf
CHANGE_LOG.txt  LICENSE.txt  readme.txt.save  udev-rule-generator
init.sh         PrintNode    resources        VERSION
pi@print-server:~/Desktop/PrintNode $
```

edit:

```
pi@print-server:~ $ systemctl status PrintNode.service
* PrintNode.service - PrintNode Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/PrintNode.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-11-01 12:51:05 CET; 177ms ago
 Main PID: 3780 (PrintNode)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/PrintNode.service
           `-3780 /home/pi/Desktop/PrintNode/PrintNode

Nov 01 12:51:05 print-server systemd[1]: Started PrintNode Service.
```

`journalctl -b -e` gave following information, repeating on and on:

```
Nov 01 20:35:44 print-server systemd[1]: PrintNode.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 01 20:35:44 print-server systemd[1]: PrintNode.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 01 20:35:44 print-server systemd[1]: PrintNode.service: Service has no hold-off time (RestartSec=0), scheduling restart.
Nov 01 20:35:44 print-server systemd[1]: PrintNode.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 10.
Nov 01 20:35:44 print-server systemd[1]: Stopped PrintNode Service.
Nov 01 20:35:44 print-server systemd[1]: Started PrintNode Service.
```

content of one of the log files inside `/home/pi/.printnode/printnode/11/logs/` (they all seem to be the same):

```
2020-11-01 20:44:40,849  launch_linux.py       41     INFO        main                           BUILD CONFIGURATION version:4.24.1 edition:printnode develop:False info:[{"build_time":"2020-05-29T02:06:46","build_machine":{"system":"Linux","platform":"Linux-4.19.66-v7+-armv7l-with-debian-10.4","machine":"armv7l","architecture":"32bit","host":"amalthea-buster"},"client":{"commit":"094126d346c3c55c94bccfd71a3a83dcace3e2ed","datetime":"2020-05-28T22:44:33"},"clientbuildsystem":{"commit":"a64b63e29eca78ab7d08253de4524f7a17bdd8f3","datetime":"2020-02-06T20:55:50"},"clienteditions":{"commit":"5ebec172a981ca7b9cdfe0dd320a18d3196a3421","datetime":"2020-05-06T12:59:26"}},["094126d346c3c55c94bccfd71a3a83dcace3e2ed","a64b63e29eca78ab7d08253de4524f7a17bdd8f3","5ebec172a981ca7b9cdfe0dd320a18d3196a3421"]]
2020-11-01 20:44:40,854  launch_linux.py       41     INFO        main                           PYTHON  : 3.6.10+
2020-11-01 20:44:40,854  launch_linux.py       41     INFO        main                           SYSTEM  : Linux
2020-11-01 20:44:40,855  launch_linux.py       41     INFO        main                           MACHINE : armv7l
2020-11-01 20:44:40,855  launch_linux.py       41     INFO        main                           VERSION : ('debian', '10.6', '')
2020-11-01 20:44:40,857  launch_linux.py       41     INFO        main                           user, hostname, cwd : pi, print-server, /home/pi/Desktop/PrintNode
2020-11-01 20:44:40,857  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Error creating default file to /etc/PrintNode/config.conf; [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/PrintNode/config.conf'
2020-11-01 20:44:40,859  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config app-default/remove_scales_support value False
2020-11-01 20:44:40,859  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config app-default/startup_mutex value True
2020-11-01 20:44:40,860  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config app-default/headless value False
2020-11-01 20:44:40,861  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config app-default/disable_systray value False
2020-11-01 20:44:40,862  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config app-default/shutdown_on_sigint value False
2020-11-01 20:44:40,863  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config app-default/web_interface value False
2020-11-01 20:44:40,864  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config app-default/web_interface_port value 8888
2020-11-01 20:44:40,865  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config app-default/web_interface_shutdown value False
2020-11-01 20:44:40,866  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config command-line/config_file value /etc/PrintNode/config.conf
2020-11-01 20:44:40,866  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config command-line/config_file_using_default value True
2020-11-01 20:44:40,867  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config command-line/disable_printer_removal value False
2020-11-01 20:44:40,868  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config app-default/ntp_check value True
2020-11-01 20:44:40,869  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config command-line/service_discovery_params value OrderedDict()
2020-11-01 20:44:40,870  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config command-line/override_server_address value (None, None)
2020-11-01 20:44:40,870  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config app-default/log_all value False
2020-11-01 20:44:40,871  launch_linux.py       41     DEBUG       main                           Config app-default/high_dpi_gui value False
2020-11-01 20:44:40,878  injector.py           805    INFO        main                           world 73716bdc-c3c7-4678-a73e-67c5ece864e3 loaded ok from /home/pi/.printnode/printnode/11/configuration.json
2020-11-01 20:44:41,089  injector.py           577    INFO        Qt                             Qt: v4.8.7, PyQt: v4.12.1, sip: v4.19.3
```

Comment: Create your local systemd files in /etc/systemd/system.

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/118003/edit) your question and add the output of this command to it: `cat /home/pi/Desktop/PrintNode`. What is the `driverobot.service`?

Comment: Added! `driverbot.service` was my mistake, which I corrected in my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

> Program is placed in a file in desktop

and

> it is supposed to work by typing ./PrintNode inside the file - which works, when I do it.

This has confused me. It seems you mean "directory" instead of "file". Then I assume, from the command line with user **pi** this runs successful:

```
rpi ~$ cd ~/Desktop/PrintNode
rpi ~$ ./PrintNode
```

To reflect this in a new Unit file, first delete your old service. It violates some general guidelines.

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable PrintNode.service
rpi ~$ sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/PrintNode.service
```

Then create a new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl edit --force --full PrintNode.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=PrintNode Service
After=graphical.target

[Service]
User=pi
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Desktop/PrintNode
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/PrintNode/PrintNode

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Enable the service and reboot.

Comment: Thank you for that response and I'm sorry for problem with file/directory.
I've set up everything according to your information, service is running but unfortunately it did't run PrintNode client on startup. When using command `/home/pi/Desktop/PrintNode/PrintNode` itself in terminal it starts normally. Is it possible that I'm missing something or I misunderstood the use of services?

Comment: @s02e16 Please edit your question and add the output of this command after a reboot to it: `systemctl status PrintNode.service`. Should PrintNode run always in the background as service, or should it run only once a short time and then successfully finish?

Comment: added to original post!

Comment: @s02e16 What does *PrintNode* do on the command line? Is there any output? A message on the command line? How do you stop *PrintNode*?

Comment: I pasted output below. It launches GUI of PrintNode client:

`pi@print-server:~ $ /home/pi/Desktop/PrintNode/PrintNode   
2020-11-01T13:18:57  info     PrintNode v4.24.1
2020-11-01T13:18:57  info     Further logs available at /home/pi/.printnode/printnode/11/logs/20201101T121857.094
2020-11-01T13:18:57  info     Application starting; pi/6864 on Linux-5.4.72-v7l+-armv7l-with-debian-10.6.`

Comment: @s02e16 To start an interactive GUI client application instead of a silent background service is an important information that you should have given earlier. Please look at the journal if you also find the text starting message there: `journalctl -b -e`. Do you find it? What do you find in `/home/pi/.printnode/printnode/11/logs/`?

Comment: I added both in original message.

Comment: i managed to slve the problem by adding `Environment=DISPLAY=:0` to the `[Service]` section. Thanks for all your help and time!

Comment: @s02e16 setting `Environment=DISPLAY=:0` is not enough. You also have to use the `graphical.target` as shown in my updated answer. It would be nice if you mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.